# Parameters, methods and inputs

Tags: java, input, methods, parameters

I am a beginner in Java and I am wondering if there is a way to use one input from the user in more than one method? I am making a program that is supposed to take some inputs (integers) from the user and control the inputs, then calculate the average and lastly count the occurrence of the inputs?

I have one main method + 3 different methods (one calculates the average etc). I have tried a lot of different things, but haven't seemed to understand the point with parameters and how they work.

So this is just a quick overview.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many elements do you want to enter");

    int value = sc.nextInt(); //Number of how many elements the user want to enter
    int[] input = new int[value]; //An array with all the values
    
}


public int secureInt(int number, int[] input, int value) { 

    if (!Integer.parseInt(number)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) { //Add all the inputs in the array
            input[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }


    public double averageCalculator (int value, int[] in){
        double average; // The average
        double sum = 0; // The total sum of the inputs

        if (int i = a; i < value; i++) {
            sum = sum + in[i];
        }
        average = sum / value;

        return average;

    }
    //Count the occurence of inputs that only occure once
    public static int countOccurence(//what parameter should i have here?) { 
        int count = 0;
      

    }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried lots of different things" what have you tried? show us some examples so we can better explain

Comment: If you have not already done so, don't forget to take the [tour] and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey @emma, you could read the arguments from the command line, store them as variables, and pass those variables around to to whichever methods you want. If what I'm saying doesn't make sense to you, I recommend going through a quick beginner Java course so that you can learn some of these basic concepts. Here's a link to one of [FreeCodeCamp's free course for beginner Java on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WiJGTPuVeU)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that may be helpful to you. The idea is to try to emulate or imitate the style & best practices in this excerpt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ArrayFiller {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("How many elements do you want to enter");
            int input_element_count = sc.nextInt(); //Number of how many elements the user want to enter
            int element_count = input_element_count;
    
        int[] array = new int[element_count]; //An array with all the values
        enter_elements_of_array(array, element_count, sc);
        double average = averageCalculator(array, element_count);
        printArray(array);
        System.out.println("The average of the entered numbers is " + average);
        
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array) {

        System.out.print("The array you entered is : [");
        for (int element : array) {
            System.out.print(" " + element + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("]" + "\n");
    }
    

    public static void enter_elements_of_array( int[] array, int element_count, Scanner sc) { 
        
            for (int i = 0; i < element_count; i++) { //Add all the inputs in the array
                System.out.println("Please enter element " + (i+1) + " of " + element_count + ":");
                array[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
    }


        public static double averageCalculator ( int[] array, int element_count){
            double average; // The average
            double sum = 0; // The total sum of the inputs

            for (int i = 0; i < element_count; i++) {
                sum = sum + array[i];
            }
                average = sum / element_count;

            return average;
        }
        
        //Count the occurence of inputs that only occur once
        public static int countOccurence(int[] array) { 
            int count = 0;
            // algorithm for counting elements with cardinality of 1
            return count;
        }
    
}
```

Comment: @emma you are most welcome, there are gray arrows : one up arrow and one down arrow next to the answer I posted. Would you up vote this please? so I can help more people & be helped by other people on these forums (some unkind users erroneously downvoted my posts & now I can not ask questions or comment properly) . Thanks!
Also, have you figured out the algorithm for counting the single occurrences ?

Comment: I would like to but I can't! It tells me that I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote! Not yet, I am still figuring it out!

Comment: @emma I am new here also. I apologize I did not mean to ask you something you cannot do. Thanks for atleast telling me about it.

Comment: @ArthurW Please adhere to the Java Naming Conventions: method and variable names are written in camelCase and class names are written in PascalCase. Looking at all of your posts on Stack Overflow, I assume you're not yet accustomed to those conventions. I suggest you to update all of your posts accordingly. And you should also indent your code properly.